# Angular 4/5, pass a class reference as an @Input property?

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to figure out how to passing a class reference using an Input property, so that I can create an instance of the class myself:

```
<my-component classToCreate="{{ClassReferenceHere}}">
</my-component>
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to create a property in typescript that expects a class reference either, so I'm not sure this is possible:

```
  @Input()
  classToCreate:Class;  // doesn't work
```

Comment: `classToCreate: typeof MyClass`. FYI types are optional!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `[ ... ]` for all input directives: `<my-component [classToCreate]="ClassReference"></my-component>` ,
where `ClassReference` is defined in your **component.ts**

It's the same for all inputs e.g.
`[ngModel]="myVariable"` or `[value]="myDynamicValues"`

Also note that your child component should simply be `@Input() classToCreate`, and it should dynamically populate the typing.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I knew about the brackets, just forgot to put them in the example.